# i want to create a factorial function in python such that it returns N

Tags: python, function

According to my code which is

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        N = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i==1*2*3*...*N:
            return(N)
```

it did not produce n error when i tested with the value zero it give one but with other number i.e 7 it gave this error

```
     TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
        <ipython-input-167-5e0569aed165> in <module>
        ----> 1 factorial(7)

        <ipython-input-166-cef7895a4a43> in factorial(n)
              5         N = 1
              6     for i in range(1, n+1):
        ----> 7         if i==1*2*3*...*N:
              8             return(N)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'ellipsis'
```

and the line 7 is the problem

Comment: What's your intent with `if i==1*2*3*...*N`? That's not valid syntax.

Comment: Are you aware that `n` and `N` are different variables? Python is case sensitive.

Comment: i want to write a code to complete the entire code on line 7 such that the factorial work. if condition is not important. it could be N==1*2*3...,n or not. i don't know

Comment: Yeah, that isn't how you would do this. you need to *calculate the factorial*.

Comment: yes , it may be anything, i am only suggesting, i have tried a lot of code  and i dont what i should write in line 7 to make the factorial work.

Comment: how do i do that with respect to the code

Comment: How would you calculate the factorial of a number by hand? Start with that. Then turn it into pseudo code. Then see if you can apply that in Python

Comment: i can do it by hand but i dont know how to present it on python. can you help

Comment: Factorials involve repeated multiplication. The point of a `for` loop is that you can use it for repeated calculation. Each pass through the for loop should correspond to one of the repeated multiplications that you need to do.

Comment: i calculated as factorial(n)==1*2*3*...*n in the line 7 of the code i wrote but it still give an error

Comment: `1*2*3*...*n` means nothing in Python. It doesn't interpret `...` like you do. You need to explicitly do the multiplication, one factor at a time. Presumably you have seen an example where numbers are summed in a for-loop. Just do something similar with multiplication.

Comment: pls i use n==int(i*(i-1)*...*1) and it gave an error of unsupported operand for * i.e int and ellipsis

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would be good?

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.8/bin/python3

import itertools

def factorials_forever():
    n = 1
    for factor in itertools.count(2):
        yield n
        n *= factor

def find_which_n(n):
    for factorialno, factorial in enumerate(factorials_forever(), start=1):
        if factorial > n:
            raise ValueError('input not a valid factorial')
        if factorial == n:
            return factorialno

def main():
#    for fact in zip(range(10), factorials_forever()):
#        print(fact)

    nth = find_which_n(3628800)
    print(nth)

main()
```

HTH.

Comment: Do you really think that a generator will help OP, when they seem to not understand very basic syntax and simple for loops? This might help them down the line, but it is unlikely to help them now. Also -- you seem to have made an assumption about what the problem is based on the title rather than the content of the question. It doesn't look like they want to go from 24 to 4. They are instead completely lost in figuring out how to get from 4 to 24.

Comment: this is not what i expect , i calculated as        factorial(n)==1*2*3*...*n     in the line 7 of the code i wrote but it still give an error

Comment: pls i use n==int(i*(i-1)*...*1) and it gave an error of unsupported operand for * i.e int and ellipsis

Comment: note: the code above is a question in which i need to complete by filling the line 7 of the code and then run to confirm if it works. what i actually wrote there was wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        N = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        N *= i
    return(N)
```

so this is the ans you can try it